# GraphQL + Angular 2 services

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client

Currently every smart component has it's own apollo.watchQuery,
Which suits the principle that each component get's exactly what it asks for.

like there is 3 places pulling the same entity, but each component want something a bit different.
And I can't find a way to create a service for it.

is there a recipe to create a service for graphql entity?

Answer (score 3):

Good question!

So the whole point of using GraphQL to manage the local data of your client side, is to decouple components from each other, and regular Angular services that fetch REST API are actually creating the coupling.

`apollo-client` will take care of doing the shared work automatically.
So in your example, those 3 places, even though they are not sharing a service, `apollo-client` normalizes the data from each query and that means that they are sharing the same entity data.

So if one query updates the data of the entity, all other queries should get update as well, even if they haven't run.
If that's not case, you should check out that you have configured apollo-client well using [dataIdFromObject](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject)

But `apollo-client` is doing that while still keeping the logical decoupling, meaning that if one of those queries will change, it won't effect anything for the other 2 queries.

So you have two choices for structure in my opinion:

1. Put the `apollo.watchQuery` in a HOC (which is also common in the React world).  Now because of the way Angular works that sometimes feels a bit awkward because props are not transferred between components implicitly like React.
2. Put the `apollo.watchQuery` in a service that is **tied to the component** and placed in a folder next to each other (and maybe with the same name like - `chat-view.component.ts` & `chat-view.service.ts`.

Is might look counter intuitive to Angular developers but I think that's the best way. a service is an external dependency to a component, but in this case, you don't want to share it with other component so you won't create a single point of failure like regular services using REST create.

**An important note** - with `apollo-client 2.0` and `apollo-angular 1.0` all the above is true even if you are querying REST API from your server (or using Firebase or any other protocol..).
You can still use `Apollo` and GraphQL on your client app to get all those benefits while sending a regular REST call to your server using [`apollo-link-rest`](https://github.com/n1ru4l/apollo-link-rest)

---

Comment: I am facing the same dilemma. I don't see why regular Angular services are creating a coupling between components, the components are still decoupled, and the services are injected. I still don't like the idea of puting the queries in each component. I think the equivalent of a React HOC would be a service in Angular. But then I still don't see why it needs to be tied to the component.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets since my last answer we released this: https://medium.com/the-guild/apollo-angular-code-generation-7903da1f8559  I think that can be a much better answer to that need (we look at it as the current best practice)

Comment: We fell into this trap as well, creating separate component specific services creates a huge amount of additional files with no benefit. Instead start thinking of apollo as your ONLY service. Your entire app should communicate via graphql. Queries should be composed and executed right in the component. If you have shared business logic do NOT hide the queries behind angular services but create client side resolvers (yes that's a thing).
There is no downside to this approach besides a bad belly feeling when you start out but thats due to graphql simply providing more than what we are used to.